# What happens to the sum of Bernouilli RVs divided by $ \sqrt(n)$

Tags: probability

Suppose I have $$S=\frac {\sum_1^nX_i} {\sqrt(n)} $$ 
where $X_i$ is Bernouilli($p$) and $n$ goes to infinity. It doesn't look like it's approximately normal (the CLT doesn't apply since it's not divided by its standard deviation), the law of large numbers doesn't apply since $n$ factors out :

$$Var(S) = \frac{nVar(X_i)}{n} = Var(X_i)$$

And it's also not a binomial, since that's the sum of Bernouilli RVs and not the sum divided by a constant.

Am I missing anything or is it something else entirely? Thanks!

Comment: It *is* approximately normal. The mean happens to be large.

Comment: Can you please show how, or at least give an outline? Thanks!

Comment: It is easy to see that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p)$, so ${\rm E}[S] = np/\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n} p$.  As $n \to \infty$, ${\rm E}[S] \to \infty$ unless $p = 0$.  For "large" but finite $n$, $S$ is approximately normal with mean $\mu = \sqrt{n} p$ and variance $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)$.

Comment: There is nothing to show. Any sum of iid "nice" random variables is approximately normal. In this case the mean is large and the variance is $\sigma$. The normal distribution with this mean and variance can be used to approximate probabilities that involve this r.v.